# Customizer: How to change Header Image description

Tags: php, theme-customizer

In the Header Image panel, there is a description that says:

*Click “Add new image” to upload an image file from your computer. Your theme works best with an image with a header size of 1200 × 280 pixels — you’ll be able to crop your image once you upload it for a perfect fit.*

I'm trying to change this text with this:

```
$wp_customize->get_control( 'header_image' )->description = 'New text here';
```

But its not working. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `description` param unfortunately is not used in this control. You can see that the message is [hard-coded in the control's template](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4af1237176c326e7840361fd580fdc3f97841e6a/src/wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-header-image-control.php#L174). That should be changed in core, but in the mean time, you can enqueue some JS at the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action with the dependency of `customize-controls` which does this:

```
wp.customize.control( 'header_image', function( control ) {
    control.deferred.embedded.done( function() {
        var el = control.container.find( '.customize-control-description' );
        el.html( control.params.description );
    } );
} );
```

This JS will continue to work if the control's `description` param starts to be used in core in a future release.

Comment: Perfect, as usual!

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_header_image_desc( $translated_text ) {
    if ( $translated_text == 'While you can crop images to your liking after clicking <strong>Add new image</strong>, your theme recommends a header size of %s pixels.' ) {
        $translated_text = 'New Description here';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_header_image_desc', 20 );
```

This is case-sensitive so type it exactly as you see it on your WordPress Theme.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. Do you know if there's a way to do it inside `customize_register` like all other controls?

Comment: this is actual file which is generating that text [ wp-includes\customize\class-wp-customize-header-image-control.php]  copy the text from this file and paste into function like i did.